# "Module does not exist in the Haste module map" when creating my own module

Tags: react-native, node-modules

I try to create my own npm module for react-native. I have created one and wanted to test it locally, but I have a dependency problem.

I have generated a module with react-native-create-library and modify the generated files with tested and working code.
In other directory, I have created a new project and test it.
I have added the module to the directory with `npm install /path/to/myModule`.
But when i try to import the module on my empty project, I have the error `Module 'myModule' does not exist in the Haste module map`.

My package.json in my empty project:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.8.3",
  "react-native": "0.59.8",
  "myModule": "file:path/to/myModule"
},
...
```

I import the module like this

```
import myModule from 'myModule';
```

I want to generate a working module. I don't really know where this problem comes from, so ask me if you want to see other parts of my code.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem trying to reference the local file deps but the only way I managed to resolve this was to put "my-module" in a separate git repo and in my package.json under dependencies:

`"my-module": "git+https://github.com/my-module.git"`

Hope this helps in some way.